# Can't generate CSS link with php

Tags: php, css

I am using PHP to generate layout for some pages, the trouble is, it just don't seem to be able to find my custom CSS file. Here is the code that I am using:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="' . $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/CSS/jokesStyle.css">
```

Note: it is a php string in which I am using it. The CSS file is located in htdocs/CSS.
Here is the path generated in browser:

```
C:/xampp/htdocs/CSS/jokesStyle.css
```

no CSS rules from this file applies to the generated page.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not simply use `<link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/jokesStyle.css">` It usages relative path to the CSS file.

Comment: `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` contains the path in the server's filesystem. The browser won't (shouldn't) allow that to be loaded on your local development machine, and definitely will not be able to load it when your site moves to a hosted webserver. You need to use something like `/CSS/jokesStyle.css` or `http://localhost/CSS/jokesStyle.css` to access the CSS file from the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code

```sh
<?php  
    if(isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on'){  
         $url = "https://";   
    }else{  
         $url = "http://";
    }
    $url.= $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; 
    $url .= "/CSS/jokesStyle.css";
    echo "<link rel='stylesheet' href='{$url}'>";
?>
```

Comment: Thanks! it worked, however now the page aren't updating correctly with the file.

Comment: I tried restarting the server and it updated. However, is there a way to update it without all that bother?

Comment: Ummm, I can't get this issue, I guess you mean your CSS changes are not visible sometimes, if this is your issue, then the solution is using ```CTRL```+```SHIFT```+```R``` to reload, this will clear all caches and load all assets and css again.

Answer (score 0):

You can define like

```
define('ROOTINDEX','https://localhost/Your site.com');

define('ROOTCSS','http://localhost/assets/css');
```

and where you want

```
<?php echo ROOTINDEX ?>/url
<?php echo ROOTCSS ?>/file.css
```

And For live and local you can define like this

```
if($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']=="localhost")
{
define('ROOTINDEX','http://localhost/your site.com');
define('ROOTBIMG','http://localhost/your site.com/upload/banner-images');
define('ROOTLOGO','http://localhost/yoursite/upload/logo-images');  
define('ROOT','http://localhost/yoursite.com/admin');
///define('HOST', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
$server = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$password = ''; 
$database = 'localdb name';
$port = '3308';
}else{
define('ROOTINDEX','http://yoursite.com');
define('ROOTBIMG','http://yoursite.com/upload/banner-images');
define('ROOTIMG','http://yoursite.com/upload/post-images');
define('ROOTPROIMG','http://Your site.com/upload/product');
define('ROOT','http://Your site.com/admin');
//define('HOST', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
$server = 'localhost';
$user = 'username';
$password = 'Password';
$database = 'dbname';
/*$port = '3308';*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all check that do you use `echo` command correctly.

Your code can be like that

```php
echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="' . $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/CSS/jokesStyle.css">';
```

or like that

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']; ?>/CSS/jokesStyle.css">
```

When you open developer tools and see your css file is not found with error code `404` this means you are having some issue with path.

So check `var_dump($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);` path is that giving you what you want.

If `C:/xampp/htdocs/CSS/jokesStyle.css` this path is working so you need to be sure `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` must give you that `C:/xampp/htdocs`.